# get text after specific tag with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a text like

```
page.content = "<body><b>Title:</b> Test title</body>"
```

I can get the Title tag with

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
record_el = soup('body')[0]
b_el = record_el.find('b',text='Title:')
```

but how can I get the text after the b tag? I would like to get the text after the element containing "Title:" by referring to that element, and not the body element.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Referring to [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways) you might want to use the `next_sibling` of your `b_el`:

```
b_el.next_sibling    # contains " Test title"
```

"Sibling" in this context is the next node, not the next element/tag. Your element's next node is a text node, so you get the text you want.

Comment: yes I tried this, but I get AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'

Comment: Are you sure you called this on the found element? NavigableString is how BeautifulSoup calls TextNodes. Please check the type of b_el.

Comment: I included the ouput above