# Scape text after div using BeautifulSoup - .next_sibling doesn't work

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the text between divs here:

[image: dojrzewamy.pl post html structure]

I tried to use `.next_sibling` like mentioned in this post: [get text after specific tag with beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754940/get-text-after-specific-tag-with-beautiful-soup)

But it didn't work.

My current code:

```py
for pageNumber in range(1565, 1566):
    address = "https://dojrzewamy.pl/cat/3/nowe/%d/seks" % pageNumber
    page = requests.get(address)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "question"})
    for container in containers:
        h2 = container.find("div", {"class": "info"}).find("h2")
        content = container.find("div", {"class": "info"}).find("div", {"class": "clear:both"})
        desc = content.next_sibling
        print(desc)
```

Could you help me in guding how to access the text between divs using BeautifulSoup4?

Answer (score 1):

The `class` attribute is not there the second **div** you are searching.The attribute is `style`

You need to provide one more check to verify if `element is present` then find the `next_sibling`.

Try Now.

```
for pageNumber in range(1565, 1566):
    address = "https://dojrzewamy.pl/cat/3/nowe/%d/seks" % pageNumber
    page = requests.get(address)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "question"})
    for container in containers:
        h2 = container.find("div", {"class": "info"}).find("h2")
        content = container.find("div", {"class": "info"}).find("div", {"style": "clear:both"})
        if content:
           desc = content.next_sibling
           print(desc)
```

---

Here you go with simple css selector options.

```
for pageNumber in range(1565, 1566):
    address = "https://dojrzewamy.pl/cat/3/nowe/%d/seks" % pageNumber
    page = requests.get(address)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "question"})
    for container in containers:
        h2 = container.find("div", {"class": "info"}).find("h2")
        content = container.select_one("div[style='clear:both']")
        if content:
           desc = content.next_sibling
           print(desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found another solution:

```py
for pageNumber in range(1565, 1566):
    address = "https://dojrzewamy.pl/cat/3/nowe/%d/seks" % pageNumber
    page = requests.get(address)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "question"})
    for container in containers:
        h2 = container.find("div", {"class": "info"}).find("h2")
        info = container.find("div", {"class": "info"})
        print(info(text=True, recursive=False))
```