# scraping the correct date hidden after script tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to scrape the date from a webpage, and the text of the date (after script tag) is injected by JavaScript:

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="LName"><a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">[me too]</a></span>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)</script>6/23/2020&nbsp;10:00&nbsp;Tuesday
</div>
```

the correct date on this tag is 6/23/2020.
I created the code, using beautifulsoup, but it returns wrong date:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
r = requests.get(u, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

I try :

```
soup.select('div.row > script')[0].get_text()
```

returns:

```
"formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)"
```

and :

```
soup.select('div.row')[0].get_text()
```

returns:

```
"\n[me too] formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)\n"
```

when I use Chrome to inspect the tag, I can see the date text after the script tag

when I execute:

```
soup.select('div.row')
```

it returns the tag without the date text

the text of the date injected by JavaScript, I need to scrape it using Beautifulsoup only, not using selenium

Comment: The date you're after isn't inside the script tag though, no? You can see the `</script>` just before it.

Comment: yes, you are right, I edited the title

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get text after specific tag with beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754940/get-text-after-specific-tag-with-beautiful-soup)

Comment: the text is injected by Javascript, and I need to scrape it using Beautifulsoup only, not using selenium

Comment: That’s a different question entirely, no?

Comment: I will create a new question then

Answer (score 1):

The date `6/23/2020` is *sibling* to `<script>` tag. You can use `.find_next_sibling(text=True)` to get this text.

For example:

```
txt = '''<div class="row">
    <span class="LName"><a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">[me too]</a></span>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)</script>6/23/2020&nbsp;10:00&nbsp;Tuesday
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

d = soup.select_one('div.row > script').find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
print(d)
print(d.split()[0])
```

Prints:

```
6/23/2020 10:00 Tuesday
6/23/2020
```

Comment: @KhaledKoubaa Probably the text you see is injected by JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. Try to do `print(soup)` and see if it's there

Comment: yes, I think so, when I do soup.select('div.row') it returns the tag without the text, but when I use Inspect on chrome, I see the text

Comment: @KhaledKoubaa So yes, it's injected by JavaScript - you can try `selenium` or other methods (`re` module, `json` module, etc...)

Comment: you can help me to do it with re (or other) and beautifulsoup without the need of selenium ? please, I prefer not using selenium

Comment: @KhaledKoubaa To not clutter the comment section I recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow. You can describe the problem there + put the problematic URL and expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216850/discussion-between-khaled-koubaa-and-andrej-kesely).