# Get table contents only after specific span content in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having an html file with several div's and no class or id names:

```
<div><span>Item 1</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>

<div><span>Item 2</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>

<div><span>Item 3</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>

<div><span>Item 4</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>
```

Goal:
I want to pick up content of a **table** only after **Item 3**, and the search to be general, to get any table **after** a specific Item number. Mind you, the number of Items may vary.

Tried:
I tried this code:

```
if soup.find('span') == 'Item 3. Selected Financial Data':
    table_tag = soup.find('tbody')
```

but it still returns the first table from the top. 
I also tried looking at .next_siblings and .next_element but isn't there a better way to accomplish this?
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways

There is a similar question here: [get text after specific tag with beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754940/get-text-after-specific-tag-with-beautiful-soup), but it does not concern tables within div's.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `find_all_next`:

```
table = soup.find(text='Item 3').find_all_previous()[2].find_all_next()
```

My full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div><span>Item 1</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>

<div><span>Item 2</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>

<div><span>Item 3</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>

<div><span>Item 4</span></div>
<div>some content</div>
<div><table><tbody>table content</tbody></table></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

table = soup.find(text='Item 3').find_all_previous()[2].find_all_next()

table_html = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in table])
```

Output:

```
>>> table
[<div><span>Item 3</span></div>, <span>Item 3</span>, <div>some content</div>, <div>table content<table><tbody></tbody></table></div>, <table><tbody></tbody></table>, <tbody></tbody>, <div><span>Item 4</span></div>, <span>Item 4</span>, <div>some content</div>, <div>table content<table><tbody></tbody></table></div>, <table><tbody></tbody></table>, <tbody></tbody>]

>>> table_html
'<div><span>Item 3</span></div><span>Item 3</span><div>some content</div><div>table content<table><tbody></tbody></table></div><table><tbody></tbody></table><tbody></tbody><div><span>Item 4</span></div><span>Item 4</span><div>some content</div><div>table content<table><tbody></tbody></table></div><table><tbody></tbody></table><tbody></tbody>'
```

Comment: Based on you answer, I noticed the following could also work, but not sure if it generalizes well: `table = soup.find(text='Item 3').find_next('tbody')`

Comment: BTW, if my answer has helped u, pls upvote my ans and accept it as the best ans. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my question to include <table><tbody> tags

Comment: I modified it slightly, specifically to my needs but it works. Thank you!